# "None" as return from while loop

Tags: python

I have the following function:

```
def AdjustTime(f):
    if len(f) == 1:
        return '0' + f + '00'
    elif len(f) == 2:
        return f + '00'
    elif len(f) == 3:
        return '0' + f
    elif len(f) == 4:
        return f
    else:
        while True:
            if len(f) > 0 and len(f) <= 4 and int(f[:2]) <= 23 and int(f[2:]) <= 59:
                return f
                break
            else:
                clear()
                print f,'Get this date right'
                f = raw_input('')
```

It works until I get a correct number, which leads to a TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable. How to fix this?

EDIT: First, thanks for the parenthesis mentions, I forgot it a few times while coding myself, now the code is the one I'm actually trying.

I want to put a string of text brought from Drafts into this function, the if/elif will convert a 1-2-3 string into the 4-digit I need and how I want it. For example, a string "1" will become "0100". But you know that. If the user screwed up somehow I'm using that while. Yes, I should reorganize it some other way, such as using the `int(f[:2]) <= 23 and int(f[2:]) <= 59` before actually trying to edit the string.

Back on track, if the user screwed up, the input gives him the chance to insert a correct string, which passes through the while. The problem is, when the user puts the correct value, this is what a `print f` shows, considering the value as 1234:

```
1234
None
```

Now, what else can I do to help you?

EDIT2: Since everybody has been asking for the whole code, you're here to help me out, I just didn't thought it was necessary. Apologies for that (:

```
from urllib import quote
import time
from webbrowser import open
from console import clear

rgv = ['a path', 'This is an awesome reminder\nWith\nMultiple\nLines.\nThe last line will be the time\n23455']

a = rgv[1].split('\n')

reminder = quote('\n'.join(a[:(len(a)-1)]))

t = a[len(a)-1]

def AdjustTime(f):
    if len(f) == 1:
    return '0' + f + '00'
    elif len(f) == 2:
        return f + '00'
    elif len(f) == 3:
        return '0' + f
    elif len(f) == 4:
        return f
    else:
        while True:
            if len(f) > 0 and len(f) <= 4 and int(f[:2]) <= 23 and int(f[2:]) <= 59:
                return f
                break
            else:
                clear()
                print 'Get this date right'
                f = raw_input('')

mins = int(AdjustTime(t)[:2])*60 + int(AdjustTime(t)[2:])

local = (time.localtime().tm_hour*60+time.localtime().tm_min)

def findTime():
    if local < mins:
        return mins - local
    else: 
        return mins - local + 1440

due = 'due://x-callback-url/add?title=' + reminder + '&minslater=' + str(findTime()) + '&x-source=Drafts&x-success=drafts://'

open(due)
```

Comment: No need for `break` after `return` statement. you should show sample input/output

Comment: f is a very bad variable name. Please read pep8 standards.

Comment: The last `int()` in the if statement is missing a `)`

Comment: you're missing a `)` on the `if len(f) > 0 ...` line. So obviously we're not looking at the code you are actually running

Comment: `len(f) > 0 and len(f) <= 4` is better written as `0 < len(f) <=4`

Comment: The `if len(f) > 0 and len(f) <= 4 and` part is unreachable, because the function will have already returned for any length in 1,2,3,4.

Comment: What are you passing to the function when you get that error? And what is the traceback of the error?

Comment: @MarkR.Wilkins: By then there could be a new `f`, thanks to the line `f = raw_input('')`.

Comment: You are missing a bracket here on your last `int(f[2:])`

Comment: Another thing is that its impossible for `raw_input` to return `None`, so the function must be being passed `None`.

Comment: @MarkR.Wilkins: That part if for the case when `f` is not valid, and being updated by the else part inside the `While True`.

Comment: You added the `)` in, but you can't fool us that easily. If f were None, `len(f)` would fail. Show us the real code and the real traceback

Comment: @Smac89 Thank you for the break/return indication. I never used `break` before.

Comment: @0xc0de Definitely a bad variable name, sorry for that. Thank you for the `0 < len(f) <= 4` tip. I knew there was a way to do it, but I couldn't remember.

@gnibbler Fooling you was never the goal. What's the point of coming over here to make helpful folks as fools? Didn't mean to waste your time either. There's the full code and the traceback is exactly as I stated in the initial post. Is there anything further I can do to improve the traceback?

Comment: @PhillipGruneich, it's still not apparent to me how that error can come from that code. I notice that the second code block has a `tab` indenting the first `return`. Be careful with mixing tabs and spaces for indenting. It can lead to hard to notice bugs.

Comment: @gnibbler Funny thing is that I can't make it show up either anymore, leading me to believe Pythonista was screwing with me somehow. The lack of the parenthesis as we commented before would give me a ValueType error, which is not the case. The only problem is that, if the code falls into the while loop and you get it right, it won't return the value and proceed the first time, you gotta type it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def AdjustTime(f):
    f = f or ""   # in case None was passed in
    while True:
        f = f.zfill(4)
        if f.isdigit() and len(f) == 4 and int(f[:2]) <= 23 and int(f[2:]) <= 59:
            return f
        clear()
        print f, 'Get this date right'
        f = raw_input('')
```

Comment: I like this approach but the OP might not know what `zfill` does.

Comment: Thank you. I quickly checked the documentations to find out what `zfill` does.

Comment: I also had completely forgotten about the isdigit(). Thanks again (:

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize f to say, `""`. In the first itereation of `while True` f is `None`, so in the `if` condition it's testing `None[:2]` and `None[2:]` which will obviously  raise error.

EDIT: Well I wonder why don't you get

```
object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

error first....

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your method, add this:

```
def AdjustTime(f):
   if not f:
      return
```

This will prevent the method from executing if you have passed it a ["falsey" value](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/truth.html).

In order to do this however, you'll need to change your logic to have the `raw_input` line in the caller of this function; because the above method will return and the prompt will never be shown:

```
def AdjustTime(f):
    if not f:
       return
    if len(f) == 1:
        return '0' + f + '00'
    if len(f) == 2:
        return f + '00'
    if len(f) == 3:
        return '0' + f
    if len(f) == 4:
        return f
    if 0 > len(f) <= 4 and int(f[:2]) <= 23 and int(f[2:] <= 59:
        return f

def get_input():
    f = raw_input('')
    result = AdjustTime(f)
    while not result:
        print('{} get this date right'.format(f))
        f = raw_input('')
        result = AdjustTime(f)
```

@gnibbler has a great suggestion in the comment:

```
def AdjustTime(f):
   f = f or ""
```

This will set the value of `f` to a blank string if the passed in value is [falsey](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/truth.html). The benefit of this method is that your if loops will still run (since a blank string has length), but your while loop will fail.

Comment: Shouldn't `object of type 'NoneType' has no len()` be the error if this was the case?

Comment: No, because I'm not checking for length; but rather the truth value of the object (see the link in my answer).

Comment: `f = f or ""` is better, so you fall through to the while loop

Comment: What I am saying is this doesn't seem to be the cause of the bug. Otherwise len() would have errored out earlier than indexing.

Comment: @0xc0de, see my comment on the question. The error is produced by different code to that in the question.